# very slow search and update database operation

Tags: php, mysql, performance, sql-delete

i have a table "table1" which has almost 400,000 records. There is another table "table2" which has around 450,000 records.

I need to delete all the rows in table1 which are duplicate in table2. I been trying to do it with php and the script was running for hours and not completed yet. Does it really takes that much time?

> field asin is varchar(20) in table1
>
> field ASIN is Index and char(10) in table2

```
$duplicat = 0;
$sql="SELECT asin from asins";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ASIN = $row['asin'];
        $sql2 = "select id from asins_chukh where ASIN='$ASIN' limit 1";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            $duplicat++;
            $sql3 = "UPDATE `asins` SET `duplicate` = '1' WHERE `asins`.`asin` = '$ASIN';";
            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
            if($result3) {
                echo "duplicate = $ASIN <br/>";
            }
        }
    }    
}

echo "totaal :$duplicat";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can run one single sql command, instead of a loop, something like:

```
update table_2 t2 
set t2.duplicate = 1
where exists (
    select id 
    from table_1 t1 
    where t1.id = t2.id);
```

**Warning! i didn't test the sql above, so you may need to verify the syntax.**

For such kind of database operation, using php to loop and join is never a good idea. Most of the time will be wasted on network data transfer between your php server and mysql server.

If even the the above sql takes too long, you can consider limiting the query set with some range. Something like:

```
update table_2 t2 
set t2.duplicate = 1
where exists (
    select id 
    from table_1 t1 
    where t1.id = t2.id
      and t2.id > [range_start] and t2.id < [range_end] );
```

This way, you can kick of several updates running in parallel

Comment: i have done this but there are many items which this UPDATE is not marking as duplicate. please check the image in my question above.

Comment: do u mind running a query to find out what items are not updated by the update statement, but returned from your 101815 query? after running my query above, run this `SELECT * FROM asins_temp t1 WHERE t1.asin IN (SELECT ASIN FROM asins_chukh) AND t1.duplicate <> 1`. then we can figure out why they were not updated.

Comment: also, please run `select count(*) from asins_temp t1 where exists (
    select asin from asins_chukh t1 where t1.asin = t2.asin)` see if it also return 101815.

Comment: first one returned :154202 total 
second one is giving an error, Unknown column 't2.ASIN' in 'where clause'. I tried to fix it like this but still . select count(*) from asins_temp t1 where exists ( select ASIN from asins_chukh t1 where t1.asin = t2.ASIN)

Comment: sorry, the 2nd query should be `select count(*) from asins_temp t1 where exists ( select asin from asins_chukh t2 where t1.asin = t2.asin)`

Comment: Sorry , i was continuously inserting data in T2, So the results were different... thank you for helping .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, processing **RBAR** (Row By Agonizing Row) is going to be *slow*. There is overhead associated with each of those individual SELECT and UPDATE statements that get executed... sending the SQL text to the database, parsing the tokens for valid syntax (keywords, commas, expressions), validating the semantics (table references and column references valid, user has required privileges, etc.), evaluating possible execution plans (index range scan, full index scan, full table scan), converting the selected execution plan into executable code, executing the query plan (obtaining locks, accessing rows, generating rollback, writing to the innodb and mysql binary logs, etc.), and returning the results.

All of that takes time. For a statement or two, the time isn't that noticeable, but put thousands of executions into a tight loop, and it's like watching individual grains of sand falling in an hour glass.

MySQL, like most relational databases, is designed to efficiently operate on *sets* of data. Give the database work to do, and let the database crank, rather than spend time round tripping back and forth to the database.

It's like you've got a thousand tiny items to deliver, all to the same address. You can individually handle each item. Get a box, put the item into the box with a packing slip, seal the package, address the package, weigh the package and determine postage, affix postage, and then put it into the car, drive to the post office, drop the package off. Then  drive back, and handle the next item, put it into a box, ... over and over and over.

Or, we could handle a lot of tiny items together, as a larger package, and reduce the amount of overhead work (time) packaging and round trips to and from the post office.

---

For one thing, there's really no need to run a separate SELECT statement, to find out if we need to do an UPDATE. We could just run the UPDATE. If there are no rows to be updated, the query will return an "affected rows" count of 0.

(Running the separate SELECT is like another round trip in the car to the post office, to check the list of packages that need to be delivered, before each round trip to the post office to drop off a package. Instead of *two* round trips, we can take the package with us one the first trip.)

So, that could improve things a bit. But it doesn't really get to the root of the performance problem.

---

The *real* performance boost comes from getting *more* work done in *fewer* SQL statements.

How would we identify ALL of the rows that need to be updated?

```
 SELECT t.asins
   FROM asins t
   JOIN asins_chukh s
     ON s.asin = t.asin
  WHERE NOT ( t.duplicate <=> '1' )
```

(If `asin` isn't unique, we need to tweak the query a bit, to avoid returning "duplicate" rows. The point is, we can write a single SELECT statement that identifies *all* of the rows that need to be updated.)

For non-trivial tables, for performance, we need to have suitable indexes available. In this case, we'd want indexes with a leading column of `asin`. If such an index doesn't exist, for example...

```
... ON asins_chukh (asin)
```

If that query doesn't return a *huge* number of rows, we can handle the UPDATE in one fell swoop:

```
 UPDATE asins t
   JOIN asins_chukh s
     ON s.asin = t.asin
    SET t.duplicate = '1' 
  WHERE NOT ( t.duplicate <=> '1' )
```

We need to be careful about the number of rows. We want to avoid holding blocking locks for a long time (impacting concurrent processes that may be accessing the `asins` table), and we want to avoid generating a *huge* amount of rollback.

We can break the work up into more manageable chunks.

(Referring back to the shipping tiny items analogy... if we have millions of tiny items, and putting all of those into a single shipment would create a package larger and heaver than a container ship container... we can break the shipment into manageably sized boxes.)

For example, we could handle the UPDATE in "batches" of 10,000 `id` values (assuming `id` is a unique (or nearly unique), is the leading column in the cluster key, and the id values are grouped fairly well into mostly contiguous ranges, we can get the update activity localized into one section of blocks, and not have to revist most of those same blocks again...

The WHERE clause could be something like this:

```
  WHERE NOT ( t.duplicate <=> 1 )
    AND t.id >= 0 
    AND t.id <  0 + 10000
```

For the next next batch...

```
  WHERE NOT ( t.duplicate <=> 1 )
    AND t.id >= 10000
    AND t.id <  10000 + 10000
```

Then

```
  WHERE NOT ( t.duplicate <=> 1 )
    AND t.id >= 20000
    AND t.id <  20000 + 10000
```

And so on, repeating that until we're past the maximum `id` value.  (We could run a `SELECT MAX(id) FROM asins` as the first step, before the loop.)

(We want to test these statements as SELECT statements first, before we convert to an UPDATE.)

Using the `id` column might not be the most appropriate way to create our batches.

Our objective is to create manageable "chunks" we can put into a loop, where the chunks don't overlap the same database blocks... we won't need to revisit the same block over and over, with multiple statements, to make changes to rows within the same block multiple times.

Comment: I ran the update command without changing it to batches and it got executed in 2 seconds. But later found that so many values were not marked as duplicate.  asin fields in both tables are like this.
" `asin` char(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL"
" `ASIN` char(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,"

Comment: some thing strange is that , i ran the command one time and it showed me that 90,000 duplicated were marked. So i ran it again and it showed 36 more item were marked and third time it showed 0. I was NOT limiting the update as batch.

Comment: i ran the update in batches and still found that many items were skipped and the UPDATE did not mark them as duplicates.